# How to add another gui to MFC project in C++

Tags: c++, user-interface, mfc

hi
i have  MFC project with gui and i want to add another gui class to the project.
ive added the class of the new gui to the project and created a new class for it but i dont know how to run it. when i running my program i have the first gui run and i want that with a press of a button the new gui will show up. and thats what i dont know how to do.
thanks

Comment: Could you post the code started if the button is pressed and point out whre the *new* GUI should be started within the source. Please post also the API of the *new* GUI -- I thing your are talking about a GUI control, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In the first gui run, handle the onbncicked event of the button and in that function derive an object  of new gui and for that object call DoModal function. This will make your second gui to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Some details are required. What is ur 2nd GUI like? is it a derived from a Dialog class or it is CWnd derived window? I assume it should be a CWnd derived window coz if it were a dialog you could have displayed it simply by calling DoModal or Create functions.

So for a CWnd derived window class, you should make a public function and in that function do the following thing:

1. Make a public function for instance "**MyWindowMajic()**"
2. Inside **MyWindowMajic()** register your class for the new Window using the **AfxRegisterWndClass()** and store the returned class name.
3. Call the **CreateEx()** function with appropriate parameters and passing it the class name you obtained in step 2. For instance: **CreateEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW,  pszClassName**, ...)
4. make a call to **ShowWindow(SW_SHOW)** to make it visible. This will end the **MyWindowMajic()** function
5. On the button's on click method, create an instance of your class and call this **MyWindowMajic()**